# Symfony Length assert doesn't work when using an umlaut (or another unicode character) with a doctrine field with a string limit in oracle db

Tags: oracle, symfony, doctrine

Long descriptive title out of the way..

The problem is that if I have a doctrine field defined as such

```php
    #[ORM\Column(name: 'department', length: 50, nullable: true)]
    #[Assert\Length(max: 50)]
    protected ?string $department;
```

Supplying a string with exactly 50 characters works just fine, as expected.

However, specifying `Laboratorio de Análisis por Activación Neutrónica` (which is 49 characters long) ends up throwing a constraint violation on the database, complaining that the string is 52 characters, over the 50 character limit.

This is because (rightfully so) `Assert\Length` uses `mb_strlen` under the hood, but the actual character size going into the DB is longer.

I've tried looking into how the database stores data, and the connection string uses `charset=AL32UTF8` which I believe is correct (at least for connection)? I could be very wrong, I don't know Oracle DB as much as I know MySQL/MariaDB and Postgres.

I've run the following to see how format is set on the columns

```sql
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, DATA_LENGTH, CHARACTER_SET_NAME
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE OWNER = 'DB_NAME' AND TABLE_NAME = 'TBL_NAME'
```

| COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE | DATA_LENGTH | CHARACTER_SET_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DEPARTMENT | VARCHAR2 | 50 | CHAR_CS |
| POSITION | VARCHAR2 | 100 | CHAR_CS |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I've looked into what `CHAR_CS` is and all I've really been able to gatheris that it's some sort of translation mode for when data comes in? Again I'm not exactly sure what's going on under the hood and could definitely use some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @MT0's answer, I was able to resolve the issue with the following:

`services.yml`

```yaml
  oci8.varchar:
    class: App\DBAL\Driver\OCI8\VarcharSession
    tags:
      - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: wrap }
```

`App\DBAL\Driver\OCI8\VarcharSession.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\DBAL\Driver\OCI8;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Middleware;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Middleware\AbstractDriverMiddleware;
use SensitiveParameter;

class VarcharSession implements Middleware {

    public function wrap(Driver $driver): Driver {
        return new class ($driver) extends AbstractDriverMiddleware {
            public function connect(#[SensitiveParameter] array $params) {
                $connection = parent::connect($params);

                $connection->exec(
                    'ALTER SESSION SET'
                        .  " NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = 'CHAR'"
                );

                return $connection;
            }
        };
    }

}
```

This meant that any time I ran `doctrine:migrations:diff`, the generated queries would define varchar types as `VARCHAR(50 CHAR)` (note it's using `CHAR` instead of the default inferred `BYTE` mode).

---

This doesn't change the behaviour of existing columns and they will need to be altered.

I used the following SQL query to give me a list of all the columns that use VARCHAR2:

```sql
select owner, table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length, data_precision
from all_tab_columns
where owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
and data_type = 'VARCHAR2';
```

The CSV output of this was then used to create doctrine migration file filled with `ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME MODIFY COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR2(DATA_LENGTH CHAR)` statements to convert all existing columns.

---

Once the migration is done, and the session is in place, everything transparently works as normal. There is no need to change the way Symfony Length assertions are counted (by using `countUnit` on the constraint - which would also have undesirable effects).

---

*Bonus tip*: Setting `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = 'CHAR'` can be set database wide, alleviating the need for the session extension mentioned earlier. However, if your database is shared with other schemas, they too will be affected as the setting is not scoped to certain schemas. This was the issue in my case and thus I opted setting the parameter in the session to avoid messing with other applications.

Answer (score 0):

The Symphony [Length documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Length.html) gives the option:

> #### `countUnit`
>
> type: `string` default: `Length::COUNT_CODEPOINTS`
>
> The character count unit to use for the length check. By default `mb_strlen` is used, which counts Unicode code points.
>
> Can be one of the following constants of the Length class:
>
> - `COUNT_BYTES`: Uses `strlen` counting the length of the string in bytes.
> - `COUNT_CODEPOINTS`: Uses `mb_strlen` counting the length of the string in Unicode code points. This was the sole behavior until Symfony 6.2 and is the default since Symfony 6.3. Simple (multibyte) Unicode characters count as 1 character, while for example ZWJ sequences of composed emojis count as multiple characters.
> - `COUNT_GRAPHEMES`: Uses `grapheme_strlen` counting the length of the string in graphemes, i.e. even emojis and ZWJ sequences of composed emojis count as 1 character.

You appear to want to count bytes as the ORM appears to be using `VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)` for the underlying column (and not `VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)`, [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rz4zFyEH)) and would want to include the option `countUnit: Length::COUNT_BYTES` to get Symphony to mimic the database behaviour. Otherwise, you need to fix your migrations to get the database to size the column based on characters, not bytes.

Comment: I did come across this, but this was only recently introduced in Symfony 6.2, which I am not running. Furthermore, I'd prefer that the DB encoding is set properly, and if I'm setting a 50 character limit on a field, I want it to actually be 50 characters.

Comment: @SteppingHat You can try setting the `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` to `CHAR` in the session before running the migrations to create the table (but that would potentially change all the string columns); or see if you can manually edit the migrations to `VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)` for the column's data type; or you can log into the database and use `ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY ("DEPARTMENT" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR))` (but that might get overwritten by a later migration); or you can create a new migration to try to make the change.